# Advantages vs Disadvantages when Loading CSS with (pure) Javascript

Tags: javascript, css

Are their any disadvantages \ advantages of loading CSS files with Javascript?

This is the reason I ask,
I have a div that mimicks a physical A4 Portait Page. And the CSS loads perfect, no problems. But suppose I wanted to make a company letter head class, so it would basically look exactly the same as an A4 Page, but with an added company logo at the top of the page, I know I can't do this with css, its purely styling, but if i were to load the css links with javascript then customize the page depending on its class name i know i can achieve this....

so my question:load and customizes all the necessary stuff
 2. in that defaultstyles.js file, i want to automatically add the image tag with the company logo in at the top of the necessary page.

Are there any disadvantages\advantages of loading css with javascript?

Thanks in Advance

EDIT:
Just to add more detail to my dillema, this is what I have

**CURRENT:**

1. a page with a div who's className is 'A4Portrait'
2. a defaults.css linked to that page that customizes the 'A4Portrait' class.
3. an image tag with the company logo at the top to mimic a letterhead

**PROPOSED**

1. load all styles with a javascript file (let's say defaultstyles.js) that runs on page load and customizes all the necessary stuff
2. in that defaultstyles.js file, i want to automatically add the image tag with the company logo in the respective div.

**NOTE**

I'm not asking how to do it, I know already, just the advantages and disadvantages of doing it the **PROPOSED** way

Comment: Why can't you add the letterhead with CSS?

Comment: well the letterhead is an image, what i've been doing already is loading it with an img tag. just wondering if there was a quicker way of doing this. like an all in one solution, well there is, just wanted to know the advantages of doing it that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend putting the css for letterhead in the same file that has all the rest of the styling.

The disadvantage of loading the css with js is that you'll create unnecessary http connections. And it will be much slower because you'd have to wait for page to load to run js.

Edit: I guess it would be fair to mention the advantage:
On the other hand, it depends. If your css for the letterhead is huge (I doubt it) and the letterhead style is only used rarely (only when printing etc.), then using js to load the extra css might be useful. But you'd only gain a bit of bandwidth and the css will probably be in cache anyway since it's intranet site so it's probably not worth the effort.

Another edit since I read the updated question:
All of the above applies if you add the image tag with js except that won't cause more http connections.

Comment: ok so this is what i have, a company intranet site that im developing, with a defaults.css file that, well, loads defaults for every page such as font-family and (in this example specifically) an A4PortraitPage class style (which is a div). so you're saying put the styling in defaults.css? which i've already done. but anyway thanks for that answer, I was looking for something that changed load times, if i slows down the process then i'm going to stick with traditional way of doing things. thanks

Comment: thanks for that <robotvoice>user2079303</robotvoice>!

Comment: unmarked as answer just to hear other suggestions...